# Arcpy - Out of memory

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcpy, python-script-tool, code-review

I'm new at making scripts and I´m having some issues in my first arcpy script.

I've created a code that automates maps creation, and it's running ok but gradually increases the memory consumption until the memory become full, the process stops and arcmap exhibits an "out of memory" message.

I've used the arcpy.Delete_management() to try to clean up the memory, but is not affecting so much the memory cleaning...

Is there another way to clean the memory?

The link to the code is posted below...

I posted the link because the code is too large to paste here in gis.stackexchange

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7468mS6n7QJUHdLUUl1Ym5lcUk/view?usp=sharing

Please, remember that I´m a scripting rookie

Comment: Out of memory is typically associated with a logical error. That is to say that you are looping something infinitely. My reccomendation is to use a lot of print statements at the beginning of your loops to see what loops runs to infinity. put a print ('Loop 1 Running ') .... at the start of any loop, and trial and error until you find your problem, or just put it on all of them.

Comment: This is more of a general code enhancement question than a GIS specific one. In general you have to look for objects that are not needed anymore by the script and do not go out of scope - e.g. by beeing set to `None`, beeing deleted or automatically garbage collected after a loop is done. I suggest you read up on [Python memory management](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/memory.html) and [Python memory profiling](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) to pinpoint where exactly you are creating the memory error.

Comment: Note that `arcpy.Delete_management() ` does *not* generally clean up memory -- it cleans up *disk* -- using `del` removes objects from memory in Python.  If your code is too large to fit inline, then you haven't taken the time to create an  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Splitting your code into standalone components to achieve the "Minimal" part will help you identify what code to evaluate.

Comment: Hello Martin... I think the problem is not about "running infinitely" because in the first "for" statement the search is made in a shapefile table... when the shapefile table has 500 lines, the script runs ok... when the shapefile table has 1000 lines, arcmap exhibits the message "out of memory"...

Comment: Kersten... your tip is a good one... I´ll try to use the "Python memory profiling" to look where is the memory accumulation... I tried to install it, but without success... is just download, unzip and run the command $ python setup.py install in the Python command line?

Comment: Vince... I already tried to use 

    for lyr in lyrlist:
     del lyr

But the full memory problem remains the same.

Comment: Vince... I´ll try to apply the MCVE... as soon as possible I'll give some feedback

Comment: Code reviews being off-topic is in a policy written some time ago at http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317/code-review-for-a-specific-piece-of-code

Answer (score 4):

Aside from the comments about memory management techniques, I wanted to give some thoughts about the code to see if it helps.

You could look into using the `arcpy.da.SearchCursor` instead of the `arcpy.SearchCursor` as it will improve speed and possibly memory usage.

I am not entirely sure what the `if impLyr01 == 1:` sections are doing.  You assign the variables at the top of your script, but I don't see any reassignment happening.  So when you're comparing the values within the cursor like that, you are going to get the result every time.  I am *assuming* that isn't your intent.    I also see a couple calls to `arcpy.RefreshActiveView()` in there.  You might be able to reorder your code and only call it once per iteration.

You code could use some formatting niceties done to it.  For instance, when you're comparing your `text_elm.text` values, you could move that into a function that returns a value.  It helps readability and also debugging.  Another readability thing you could use is the [`.format()` or `%`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format) methods.

Aside from those pieces above to help you sort through the code, one option you may find useful is to create the majority of your variables *before* going into the cursor loop.  This way, you're not assigning them multiple times.  You may have the problem of the garbage collector not being able to keep up with the amount of items you're creating.  You may want to look into using the [`del`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146963/when-is-del-useful-in-python) keyword to see if that helps clear up your memory.

Lastly, add a few messages to your script `arcpy.AddMessage()` so you can monitor your script's progress.  You could [output your memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938733/total-memory-used-by-python-process) usage, too.  This would be a good way to section out your code (functions work great too) with messages to let you better get a feel for what is going on, and how much memory is being used.

Other than that, you may find the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) a better place for this question as it is not really GIS related, but it is more python related.